# extract different strings after match using R

Tags: r, string

```
data <- c("Demand =  001   979", "Demand =  -08   976 (154)", "Demand =  -01   975 (359)")
data <- str_match(data, pattern = ("Demand = (.*) (.*)"))
```

I need to extract the first 2 sets of numbers (including the - sign) into columns using `str_match`.
Exclude 3rd set of numbers in bracket ().
Any help is welcomed.

**Output**:

```
## [1] "001" "-08" "-01"
## [2] "979" "976" "975"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about removing everything else?

```
data <- c("Demand = 001 979", "Demand = -08 976 (154)", "Demand = -01 975 (359)")
data <- gsub("Demand = ", "", x = data)
data <- trimws(gsub("\\(.*\\)", "", x = data))

out <- list()

out[[1]] <- sapply(data, "[", 1)
out[[2]] <- sapply(data, "[", 2)
out

[[1]]
[1] "001" "-08" "-01"

[[2]]
[1] "979" "976" "975"
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibility with `str_extract_all()` from `stringr`:

```
sapply(str_extract_all(x, "-?[0-9]+?[0-9]*"), function(x) x[1])

[1] "001" "-08" "-01"

sapply(str_extract_all(x, "-?[0-9]+?[0-9]*"), function(x) x[2])

[1] "979" "976" "975"
```

Or using the idea of @Roman Luštrik with `strsplit()`:

```
sapply(strsplit(gsub("Demand = ", "", x), " "), function(x) x[1])

[1] "001" "-08" "-01"
```

Comment: Meh, I tried fetching all integer _and_ a minus sign within the square brackets and failed.